# Angular component styling issue / div overflow

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to set up a very simple component like this:

```css
.time {
  font-size: 100px;
}
.seconds {
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="time">{{ now | date: "HH:mm" }}</div>
<div class="seconds">{{ now | date: "ss" }}</div>
```

This is then displayed as in this picture.

[image]

If I remove the css code, the styling is as expected.

[image]

Where does this weired behavior come from and how can I solve this issue?

I'm using Angular v 11.2.1 including angular material.

Comment: Try to recreate that behavior in stackblitz.com 
If you can't then it seems like you are having some local or global css rule/s that overrides the `div` behavior.

Answer (score 0):

seem like your div display property changed. You can update css file with **display: block;** in "time" or "second" class or a new div component.

```
.time {
    display: block;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

or

```
div {
    display: block;
}
```

I hope that will help you. Thank you.